# Django Block Title Shows In Page Content

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I was trying to add a title for one of my Django HTML templates. The title of the website changes but it also shows up as text on the page content. How do I fix this and why does this happen?

base.html

```html
{% block head %}
<head>
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
{% endblock %}
```

page.html

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block head %}
{% block title %}Some Title{% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use head block just use title block

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Some Title{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to change the title, you don't need:

```
{% block head %}{% end block %}
```

You are able to directly indicate the title:

```
{% block title}Your Title{% end block %}
```

More information here (official docs)- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/language/

Comment: Hi @Tristan: It is recommended that you copy and blockquote the contents of any link you provide as links tend to die in time. Also in case they become outdated at least people can see that for certain version/time your suggestion would work.